# Hadoop read 2 files at once(one header file and one data file)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have sets of these files-

**objectA-record-data.log** file - Contains multiple lines of data with timestamps.

**objectA-record-metadata.log** file - Contains just one line. Think of it as a metadata for all the records of objectA.

Together they will form one record for processing.

I have been able to process the data file. The mapper sets objectA as the key for all the lines in the data file and reducer processes and prints the text file. Now i want to add metadata also to each of these records. Any ideas how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DistributedCache:

In the driver/configuration class:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/chris/theMetaDataFile.txt"), conf);
```

In the mapper:

```
public void setup(Context context) {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    Path[] cachedFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
    File metadataFile = new File(chachedFiles[0].toString());

    // metadataFile can now be read and the results stored locally for use in the map method
}
```

Comment: Actually, there are many metadata files, one for each object. If i load too many cache files, will it hog the system? Or may be i need to read more about how distributed cache works.

Comment: Are they all in the same directory? And how do you know which file goes with which record?

Comment: They are all in the same directory. The filename helps decide the record. The filename is something like objectA-yyyy-mm-dd. So each object has one file for each day. and the file contains information for every hour of the day which needs to be processed along with the header.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there must be some mapping between your data file and meta file
You can get the meta file in the setup method of Mapper like following

```
protected void setup(
        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<Long, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
        throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileSplit split=(FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
    Path path=split.getPath();
    Path metaFile=getMetaFile(path);
};
```

Comment: There is one file for each object, so the code should go in map() and not in setup().